# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (10, 300, 3)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write a starter code for a project for school, and this is the first time I have used machine learning or anything like this, so any help would be much appreciated. I tried to use a book for my beginning, and followed the code exactly, and understood almost everything. But I do not yet quite understand how to debug my program, and I have checked stack overflow for this issue, but I still do not quite understand how to fix this issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
import random
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import zipfile
import os

!wget --no-check-certificate \
    https://storage.googleapis.com/laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/horse-or-human.zip \
    -O /tmp/horse-or-human.zip

local_zip = '/tmp/horse-or-human.zip'
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/horse-or-human')
zip_ref.close()

train_horse_dir = os.path.join('/tmp/horse-or-human/horses')
train_human_dir = os.path.join('/tmp/horse-or-human/humans')

train_horse_names = os.listdir(train_horse_dir)
print(train_horse_names[:10])

train_human_names = os.listdir(train_human_dir)
print(train_human_names[:10])

print('total training horse images:', len(os.listdir(train_horse_dir)))
print('total training human images:', len(os.listdir(train_human_dir)))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300, 300, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/tmp/horse-or-human/',  
        target_size=(300, 300),  
        batch_size=128,
        class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=8,   
      epochs=15,
      verbose=1)

model.summary() 

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  
  path = '/content/' + fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(300, 300))
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  image_tensor = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(image_tensor, batch_size=10)
  print(classes)
  print(classes[0])
  if classes[0]>0.5:
    print(fn + " is a human")
  else:
    print(fn + " is a horse")
```

but then i get the error code

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1569 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1559 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1552 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1525 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1013 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:235 assert_input_compatibility
        str(tuple(shape)))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (10, 300, 3)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Apart from the shape mismatch error you have one huge thing missing which is the test dataset.

Comment: I just ran the model training and it works just fine. What version of Tensorflow are you using?

Comment: the model training is just fine, but when i put the image into the program, it takes the image, and then it gives me that error code

Comment: i am using google colab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake to assign batch dimension to `y` variable.

Change this line like this:

```
#y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```